# A roll-unter-Game with cashback-rate on losses.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, random-walk

Im scretching my head about the following roll-under-game:

> Choose a bet-amount $B$ and a number $N$ between $2$ and $96$.
> Then the bank picks a Number $R$ between $1$ and $100$ discretly uniformly distributed.
> If $N< R$ you won the game and get $w(N)\cdot B$ back, where ...
> $$w(N)=\frac{\beta}{P(R<N)}=\frac{\beta}{\frac{N-1}{100}}=\frac{100\cdot\beta}{N-1}$$
> ... with $P(R<N)=\frac{N-1}{100}$ and $0\leq\beta\leq1$. On the other hand, if the result is $N\geq R$ you loose a portion $\gamma\cdot B$ of your bet-amount.
>
> In the case considered here the following applies: $\beta=0.985$ and  $\gamma\in[0,1]$ (loss-ratio) with $\gamma:=1-\delta$, where $\delta\in[0,1]$ (cashback-rate). So for $\delta=0$ or else $\gamma=1$ we get the classical roll-under-game with no cashback-bonus.
>
> I'll give two quick example to illustrate the game:
>
> i) [$\beta=0.985$, $\gamma=1$ (no chashback)]: If you pick $N=51$ you will win with a probability of $50\%$ and get $1.97\cdot B$ back. In the event of a loss the entire bet-amount is lost.
>
> ii) [$\beta=0.985$, $\gamma=0.7$ (30% chashback)]: If you pick $N=51$ you will win with a probability of $50\%$ and get $1.97\cdot B$ back. In the event of a loss you will receive $0.3\cdot B$ back.

We choose a fixed number $N\in\{2,3,\ldots,96\}$, a bet-amount $B>0$ and play the game with a seed-capital of $M_0\in\mathbb{R}_+$ multiple times in a row.

Set $\omega:=W(N)-1$.
Lets define be a sequence of r.v.'s with $X_n\in\{1,0\}$ such that $X_n=1$ describes a win and $X_n=0$ represents a loss of the $n$-th game played.
Obviously $P(X_n=1)=:p=P(R<N)=\frac{N-1}{100}$ and $P(X_n=0)=:q=1-p$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, therefore $X\sim Ber(p)$.
Because $X_n$ is bernoulli distributed we know that $E[X_n]=p$.

Now we take a look at the earnings in each round. Obviosly they can be described by the sequence of r.v. $Y_n=X_n\cdot\omega B+(X_n-1)\cdot\gamma B$.
The expected value is:

$$\begin{align}E[Y_n]&=E[X_n\cdot\omega B+(X_n-1)\cdot\gamma B]\\&=E[X_n]\cdot\omega B+(E[X_n]-1)\cdot\gamma B\\&=p\cdot\omega B+(p-1)\cdot\gamma B=B(p\cdot\omega-(1-p)\cdot\gamma)\\&=B(p\cdot\omega-q\cdot\gamma)\end{align}$$

So it is a fair game with $E[Y_n]=0$ if $\omega=1$, $\gamma=1$ and $p=0.5$. We continue to simplify the expression from above with $\delta:=1-\gamma$ (Cashbackrate), $\Delta:=\beta-1$ and $\omega=W(N)-1=\frac{\beta}{p}-1$. Leading to:

$$\begin{align}E[Y_n]&=B\cdot(\omega p-\gamma q)=B\cdot((\frac{\beta}{p}-1)p-\gamma q)\\&=B\cdot(\beta-p-\gamma(1-p))=B\cdot(\beta-p-\gamma+\gamma p)\\&=B\cdot(\beta-p(1-\gamma)-\gamma)=B\cdot(\beta-p\delta-(1-\delta))\\&=B\cdot((\beta-1)+\delta(1-p)=B\cdot((\beta-1)+\delta q)\\&=B\cdot(\Delta+\delta q) \end{align}$$

In the case described at the beginning with $\beta=0.985$ and no cashback (meaning $\gamma=1$) and $N=51$ (which gives $p=0.5$) we get $E[Y_n]=B\cdot(\Delta+\delta q)=B(-0.015+0\cdot 0.5)=-0.015\cdot B$. So in a roll-under-game without any cashback on losses we expect a loss of 1.5% of the bet-amount each game. Now let's check how the cashback rate has to be changed in order to expect a profit:

$$E[Y_n]\geq 0\Leftrightarrow B\cdot(\Delta+\delta q)\geq0 \Rightarrow (\Delta+\delta q)\geq0 \Leftrightarrow q\geq\frac{-\Delta}{\delta} $$

So we expect a profitable game when $\frac{-\Delta}{\delta}<q$.
For $N=51$, $\beta=0.985$ and with a cashback-rate of $\delta=5\%,7\%,9\%,11\%,13\%,15\%$ we achieve a expected profit of $1\%,2\%,3\%,4\%,5\%,6\%$ of the bet-amount $B$ each game.
On the other hand if we choose a cashback-rate of $\delta=3\%$ we achieve a fair game.

**Is this calculation correct so far?**

For the sake of completeness we look at the capital stocks r.v.'s $M_1,M_2,\ldots$ after each round.
$M_0$ describes the overall capital at the beginning of the game.
It is clear that $M_n=M_0+\sum_{k=1}^n X_n$ applies. For the expected value we get:

$$\begin{align}E[M_n]&=E[M_0+\sum_{k=1}^n Y_n]=M_0+\sum_{k=1}^n E[X_n]=M_0+B\sum_{k=1}^n(\Delta+\delta q)\\&=M_0+n\cdot B(\Delta+\delta q)\end{align}$$

Now i try to find the probability that i am runied after $n$ games.
For this we define $W_n=\sum_{k=1}X_k$ the number of wins in $n$ trails, which we know is binomial distributed $W_n\sim Bin(n,p)$.
Further we define $L_n=n-W_n$ the number of lost games in $n$ trails.
So we are bankrupt if:

$$\begin{align}M_0+W_n\omega B-L_n\cdot\gamma B\leq 0 
&\Leftrightarrow M_0+W_n\omega B \leq L_n\cdot\gamma B
\\ &\Leftrightarrow M_0+W_n\omega B \leq (n-W_n)\cdot\gamma B 
\\ &\Leftrightarrow M_0+W_n\omega B \leq n\gamma B-W_n\gamma B
\\ &\Leftrightarrow M_0+W_n B(\omega-\gamma) \leq n\gamma B
\\&\Leftrightarrow W_n\leq\frac{n\gamma B-M_0}{B(\omega-\gamma)} \end{align}$$

So the probability to get ruined after $n$ games is given by $P(W_n\leq K)$ with $K:=\frac{n\gamma B-M_0}{B(\omega-\gamma)}$.
Because $W_n\sim Bin(n,p)$ we know the cumulativ distribution function $F_{W_n}(x)$. This gives us:

$$P(W_n\leq K)=F_{W_n}(K)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor K \rfloor}\binom{n}{k}p^kq^{n-k}$$

**Is this correct? Are there any flaws? Especially the last result seems somehow strange to me.**

How can I determine the probability that I have a higher capital $M_n$ after $n$ games than at the beginning $M_0$?
Which means nothing else than, how do I calculate the probability $P(M_n\geq M_0)$?

**Is a approach through random walks better?** Basically it is a random walk with different step-sizes. It walks $\gamma B$ to the left side with probability $q=1-p$ and walks $\omega(N) B$ to the right with the probability $p=\frac{N-1}{100}$.
Is there any literature for this special case of a random-walk?

Any assistance, thoughts or comments would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have made almost 40 edits to your question since you posted it yesterday.  This is a red flag, and indicates that you might need to step back and think about what your question is and how you want to ask it.  Please stop editing your question until you have taken some time to consider what it is you really want to say.

Comment: I am really sorry. I am a non-native-speaking dyslexic. I corrected a lot of spelling mistakes and sentence construction and changed it to better formatting. Also added some examples to better introduce the topic. The overall question did not change tho: "Is the calculations of $E[Y_n]$ and $P(M_n\leq0)$ correct?" and "how to approach the problem of calculating $P(M_n\geq M_0)$. I apologize very much for my inconvenience.